# Why doesn't tcpdump run in background?

Tags: linux, shell, tcpdump, nohup

I logged in a virtual machine via ssh and I tried to run a script in background, the script is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
APP_NAME=`basename $0`
CFG_FILE=$1
. $CFG_FILE #just some variables
CMD=$2
PID_FILE="$PIDS_DIR/$APP_NAME.pid"
CUR_LOG_DIR=$LOGS_RUNNING

echo $$ > $PID_FILE

#Main script code

#This script shall be called using the following syntax
# $ nohup script_name output_dir &

TIMESTAMP=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`

CAP_INTERFACE="eth0"

/usr/sbin/tcpdump -nei $CAP_INTERFACE -s 65535 -w file_result

rm $PID_FILE
```

The result should be tcpdump running in background, redirecting the command result to file_result.

The script is called with:

```
nohup $SCRIPT_NAME $CFG_FILE start &
```

And It is stopped calling the STOP_SCRIPT:

```
##STOP_SCRIPT
PID_FILE="$PIDS_DIR/$APP_NAME.pid"

if [ -f $PID_FILE ]
then
  PID=`cat $PID_FILE`

  # send SIGTERM to kill all children of $PID
  pkill -TERM -P $PID
fi
```

When I check the file_result, after running the stop script, It is empty.

What is happening? How can I solve it?

I found this link: https://it.toolbox.com/question/launching-tcpdump-processes-in-background-using-ssh-060614

The author seems to have faced a similar issue. They debate about race conditions, but I didn't understand completely.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But It should work, the commands passed doesn't change anything.

Comment: The script is called with the '&' character, I forgot it.
I will update the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by having the startup script itself continue to run, but here's an approach that I think accomplishes what you're trying to do, namely start [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) and have it continue to run immune to hangups via [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).  I've simplified things a bit for illustrative purposes - feel free to add any variables back as you see fit, such as the `nohup.out` output directory, `TIMESTAMP`, etc.

Script #1: **tcpdump_start.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f nohup.out
nohup /usr/sbin/tcpdump -ni eth0 -s 65535 -w file_result.pcap &

# Write tcpdump's PID to a file
echo $! > /var/run/tcpdump.pid
```

Script #2: **tcpdump_stop.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /var/run/tcpdump.pid ]
then
        kill `cat /var/run/tcpdump.pid`
        echo tcpdump `cat /var/run/tcpdump.pid` killed.
        rm -f /var/run/tcpdump.pid
else
        echo tcpdump not running.
fi
```

To start **tcpdump**, just run `tcpdump_start.sh`.
To stop the **tcpdump** instance started with `tcpdump_start.sh`, just run `tcpdump_stop.sh`.

The captured packets will be written to the **file_result.pcap** file, and yes, it's a pcap file, not a text file, so it helps to name it with the proper file extension.  The **tcpdump** statistics will be written to the **nohup.out** file when **tcpdump** is terminated.

Comment: Hello Christopher.
Indeed, your solution works. However, I don't understand why mine doesn't.

I did some tests and, with my method, the tcpdump process is killed when the script finishes, even calling the script with 'nohup' and '&' character.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For people still wondering what the heck `nohup` does and what a "hangup" is: this is a really useful tutorial about `nohup`: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nohup-command-in-linux. It also explains what `nohup` does and what "hangups" mean: _"Nohup, short for no hang up is a command in Linux systems that keep processes running even after exiting the shell or terminal. Nohup prevents the processes or jobs from receiving the `SIGHUP` (Signal Hang UP) signal. This is a signal that is sent to a process upon closing or exiting the terminal."_

Comment: I recommend the syntax `"$(cat /var/run/tcpdump.pid)"` over `\`cat /var/run/tcpdump.pid\``.

Answer (score 3):

I too had faced problems when running tcpdump over an SSH session.
In my case, I was running

```
sudo nohup tcpdump -w {pcap_dump_file} {filter} > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Where, running this command over Paramiko SSH session as a **background process** was the problem.

To get around this, I used **screen** utility of Linux.
**screen** is an easy to use tool for long-running of processes as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an old post, but this is also relevant. I couldn;t understand why no file was being created only to realise that the file might not be created until a certain amount of data had been captured.
https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/485